# CORS preflight request returning 415 status 'Unsupported Media Type'

Tags: javascript, http, cors, preflight

I am currently trying to send a XMLHttpRequest in javascript to a test ASP.NET Web API that is being hosted on my IIS Express. but every time i send the request it always fails the preflight request returning a 415 error.

When trying the request in Postman i always get a successful response back. 
Can anyone help figure out what it is i am doing wrong?

My Request:

```
var data = {
                "FirstName": "test",
                "LastName": "test",
                "Email": "test.test@me.co.uk",
                "Tel": "07123456789",
                "OrganisationName": "test",
                "OrganisationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            };

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;

            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    if (this.status === 415) {
                        return;
                    }
                    alert(this.responseText);
                }

            };

            xhr.open("POST", "https://localhost:44384/api/licensecheck/Trial");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Postman request works fine because they are of same domain,hence u dont get Crossdomain issue there. Your facing cross domain problem.

Comment: @hema Any ideas on how to resolve this cross domain problem? or any pointers on where to look to solve it myself?

Comment: Recently i faced the same issue and resolved it,But am working on Springs ,can give u solution in that tech.No idea on .NET

Comment: You get crossdomain issue because your code is in one domain and your request sending is in another domain. SO this obviously happens for security reasons